# Running a slurm job array

Tags: slurm

I have a job_array.sh with 23 tasks:

```
> angsd -i ./realigned_RSFV1A.bam -anc ./BF_genome.fa -gl 1 -doSaf 1 -doSnpStat 1 -doMajorMinor 1 -doMaf 1 -doGeno 6 -doCounts 1 -doPost 1 -nThreads 24 -out ./RSFV1A -sites ./beng_wbm_par15_varcal.pos
> angsd -i ./realigned_RSFV1B.bam -anc ./BF_genome.fa -gl 1 -doSaf 1 -doSnpStat 1 -doMajorMinor 1 -doMaf 1 -doGeno 6 -doCounts 1 -doPost 1 -nThreads 24 -out ./RSFV1B -sites ./beng_wbm_par15_varcal.pos
> angsd -i ./realigned_RSFV1C.bam -anc ./BF_genome.fa -gl 1 -doSaf 1 -doSnpStat 1 -doMajorMinor 1 -doMaf 1 -doGeno 6 -doCounts 1 -doPost 1 -nThreads 24 -out ./RSFV1C -sites ./beng_wbm_par15_varcal.pos
```

...

to run in parallel using a slurm script.

I am trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mail-user 
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH -p std.q
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --oversubscribe
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00     # 24 hours
#SBATCH --output=./HET.stdout
#SBATCH --job-name=HET
#SBATCH --array=1-23
#SBATCH --export=ALL

inds="$(seq -s ' ' 1 23)"
ind=${inds[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
$ind
```

but it doesn't work

I also tried:

```
eval $(sed "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}q;d" ./job_array.sh)
```

It works but it calls the jobs one after the other not in parallel. So it is equally time consuming.

Comment: Welcome to U/L. As it stands, your question is very confusing. We have to know what the slurm job format is, and how it is submitted. Please be precise in what you want to code, and consider re-editing to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the base level, it looks like you just want to replace text in a script, but your question is ambiguous (e.g. what is `job_array.sh`, why isn't is a script (no shebang), what precisely are you running, what is `./realigned/HET/HETvarcal/het_jobarray.sh`, etc.)

Comment: job_array.sh is basically the lines I have up there. and the .slurm job file is basically the lines I have up there as well. It is submitted by running sbatch job.slurm.

Comment: I would need to run each line in job_array.sh as parallel tasks. It does seem like  eval $(sed "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}q;d" ./job_array.sh) works, but I'm not sure it's the correct way of doing this.